# Task :compileFunctionalTestGroovy FAILED during gradle ci build

Tags: gradle, azure-devops

I have task that runs a functional test

```
 - task: Gradle@2
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: ''
      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
      gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: 'build/test-results/functional-test/TEST-*.xml/TEST-*.xml'
      options: '--warning-mode all --stacktrace --info'
      tasks: 'build functionalTest'
    env:
     SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

But when I run it I get this
[image]

But I don't have it with tasks: 'build'

What the problem can it be? Maybe someone has faced this?

This is the error. The problam is with Task :compileFunctionalTestGroovy FAILED

> ```
> > Task :compileFunctionalTestGroovy FAILED
> Excluding []
> Excluding []
>   at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.visit(SpockTransform.java:64)
>   at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform.visit(SpockTransform.java:47)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:277)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:67)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:98)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.GroovyCompilerFactory$DaemonSideCompiler.execute(GroovyCompilerFactory.java:77)
>   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkAction.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:135)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker$1.create(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractClassLoaderWorker.executeInClassLoader(AbstractClassLoaderWorker.java:43)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:49)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.IsolatedClassloaderWorker.run(IsolatedClassloaderWorker.java:30)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:85)
>   at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.run(WorkerDaemonServer.java:55)
>   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction$1.call(WorkerAction.java:138)
>   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.WorkerLogEventListener.withWorkerLoggingProtocol(WorkerLogEventListener.java:41)
>   at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.request.WorkerAction.run(WorkerAction.java:135)
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>
> ```
>  Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
> Stopped 1 worker daemon(s).
> Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
>     at ExecState._setResult (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.176.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:816:25)
>     at ExecState.CheckComplete (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.176.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:799:18)
>     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/vsts/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.176.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:721:19)
>     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
>     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:230:5)
> No test result files matching /home/vsts/work/1/s/build/test-results/functional-test/TEST-*.xml/TEST-*.xml
> ```
>
> were found, so publishing JUnit test results is being skipped.
> ##[error]Error: The process '/home/vsts/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
> Finishing: Gradle

This is my graddle. B

```
    buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.pascalwelsch.gitversioner:gitversioner:0.4.2'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id "org.asciidoctor.jvm.convert" version "3.1.0"
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "5.1.0"
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '1.7.0'
    id "java"
    id "groovy"
    id "idea"
}

apply from: "gradle/integration-test.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/functional-test.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.pascalwelsch.gitversioner'

ext {
    applicationInsightsLoggingVersion = '2.6.2'

    cglibNodepVersion = '3.3.0'
    commonsLang3Version = '3.11'
    gsonVersion = '2.8.6'
    lombokVersion = '1.18.16'
    reactorVersion = '3.3.10.RELEASE'
    reactorKafkaVersion = '1.2.2.RELEASE'
    spockVersion = '1.3-groovy-2.5'
    wiremockVersion = '2.27.2'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://pkgs.visualstudio.com/7asda0d6-3cb7-46e1-99e8-572cfa3e195e/_packaging/maven/maven/v1'
        credentials {
            username "Azure DevOps Services"
            password System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
        }
    }
}

// Configure the versioner
gitVersioner {
    baseBranch "master"           // default "master"
    yearFactor 1000               // default "1000", increasing every 8.57h
    addSnapshot true              // default false, the "-SNAPSHOT" postfix
    addLocalChangesDetails false  // default true, the (<commitCount>) before -SNAPSHOT
    formatter = { gitVersioner ->
        return "${gitVersioner.versionName}".replaceAll("\\+", "-")
    }
}

group = 'com.dev'
version = "${gitVersioner.versionName}"
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) {
    groovyOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

task printVersion {
    println project.version
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring boot
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'


    // Forward logging to Azure Application insights
    implementation "com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:$applicationInsightsLoggingVersion"

    // Kafka
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'

    // Project reactor
    implementation "io.projectreactor.kafka:reactor-kafka:$reactorKafkaVersion"

    // Lombok
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

    // Other
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonsLang3Version"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"

    // Test dependencies
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation "io.projectreactor:reactor-test:$reactorVersion"
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:$wiremockVersion"

    // Spock
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:$spockVersion"
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-spring:$spockVersion"
    testRuntimeOnly "cglib:cglib-nodep:$cglibNodepVersion"
}
```

Comment: From the error message, it seems that this issue is related with the dependency:`io.jsonwebtoken`. This may be related to your project itself rather than the configuration of the pipeline. I tested with the same task settings and it could work. Can you share the `build.gradle` file with us? On the other hand, in your Yaml code, you have set the `--stacktrace --info`. It should be able to display more task log information. But in the screenshot, it doesn't show enough error message. Can you help us check this ?

Comment: Hello @KevinLu-MSFT sorry for the late responce. I added details to the question

Comment: Hi @Kirill Kiselev. I have referenced your updated information. But it still seems unable to display specific information about why the task failed. It shows some vague configuration information. And based on my test, I couldn't reproduce the same issue.  If you run the same project on your local machine, does it have the same issues?

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT. Nope. It seems this problem shows only on azure devops agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I build not whole dependencies.